# Step function example

Tags: calculus, step-function

Give an example of a step function $s:[-1,3]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $s([-1,3])$ contains at least $4$ distinct real numbers and

$\int_{-1}^3 s = \pi\,.$

$s(x)=-20 \text{ if } -1 \leq x <0$

$s(x)=\frac{\pi}{3} \text{ if }0 \leq x < 1$

$s(x)=20 \text{ if }1\leq x < 2$

$s(x)=\frac{2\pi}{3} \text{ if }2\leq x \leq 3$

This seems a little to simple I got worried could yall verify. P.S. sorry couldnt figure out how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if your example is right. That's right, just break an integral in the four ranges.